# NGINX Reverse Proxy Not Resolving server_name for Subdomains via Namecheap

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy, reverse, server-name

first post here after many hours and days on end trying to get NGINX reverse proxy to work.

I have multiple subdomains via Namecheap service pointing to home on port 80, and the router/firewall is running OpenWrt which is pointing to the internal NGINX reverse proxy server(CentOS 7) on port 80.

The subdomains for this example are dokuwiki.namecheaptld.io and observium.namecheaptld.io

Here is my main /etc/nginx.conf file:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        #listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        #include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        #location / {
        #}

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

I created a proxy_params file in /etc/nginx that previously wasn't there:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

I have 2 subdomains inside of /etc/nginx/conf.d/ named dokuwiki.conf and observium.conf:

```
upstream dokuwiki  {
      server 192.168.1.6:8180;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dokuwiki.namecheaptld.io;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/dokuwiki.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/dokuwiki.error.log;

     location / {
     proxy_pass  http://192.168.1.6:8180;
     include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
     }
}


upstream observium  {
      server 192.168.1.8:80;
}

server {
   listen      80;
   server_name observium.namecheaptld.io
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/observium.access.log  main;
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/observium.error.log;

   location / {
        proxy_pass  http://192.168.1.8:80;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to access either subdomain.namecheaptld.com, I am presented with the defined default virtual host with eith _ or default_server in the server_name block.

I am completely confused why it's not working after trying many things including adding a trailing / after the proxy_pass defined IP, and looked at the HTTP headers coming in /var/log/nginx/dokuwiki.access.log are:

```
[22/Nov/2016:09:29:54 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18273 "http://dokuwiki.namecheaptld.io/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36" "-"
[22/Nov/2016:09:29:54 -0500] "GET /lib/exe/indexer.php?id=start&1479824990 HTTP/1.1" 200 42 "http://MYEXTERNALIP/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36" "-"
[22/Nov/2016:09:29:57 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18264 "http://observium.namecheaptld.io/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36" "-"
[22/Nov/2016:09:29:57 -0500] "GET /lib/exe/indexer.php?id=start&1479824994 HTTP/1.1" 200 42 "http://MYEXTERNALIP/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

So for the above headers when I have it listening on 192.168.1.11:80, it looks like it's taking either request of dokuwiki.namecheaptld.io or observium.namecheaptld.io and processing the request as if it's dokuwiki.namecheaptld.io

I tried to use explicit wildcards in the server_name directive which did not seem to help.

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem, but why not use the more standard setup of each subdomain having its own config, placed in nginx/sites-available and symlinked in sites-enabled.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-on-centos-7

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought that the sites-available was legacy now and to put the vhosts directly into the conf.d directory? I'm open to using whichever is recommended for the current version of NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it after so much troubleshooting! Go figure the above code is completely correct if anyone would like to use it as a template.

The problem was that I had URL Redirects setup in namecheap instead of A records for each subdomain -> my external IP. Can't believe it turned out to be so simple, DNS for ya...